# Getting AppleScript to click button "+" and select "Language" and click Add

Tags: applescript

I am trying to automate via AppleScript the addition and the selection of a specific language in macOS Big Sur (for example Spanish) from System Preferences > Language & Region.

I can display the UI via this code, but I cannot get the "+" button to click.

[image: Big Sur Language & Region]

```
tell application "System Preferences"
reveal anchor "Language" of pane id "com.apple.Localization"
activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
        set i to 0
        repeat until exists button 1 of group 1
            delay 0.1
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 30 then return
        end repeat
        
        --  # Click the [+] button.
        
        click button 1 of group 1
        
        
    end tell
end tell
```

end tell

Comment: ah correct. It was mojave. But I have also the same issue with Big Sur, so I have changed the screenshot

Comment: This works for me: `tell application "System Events" to click UI element 1 of group 2 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"`

Comment: Cool, that's one step, and How do I select a specific language in the language list (i.e Spanish)

Comment: From what language will the _script_ run?  What is the exact name of the one you want?

Comment: The script will be run with only English in the language list, so it will be run from English.
I want a series of different scripts to add one language only and select that language as default language within the list {French, Japanese, Korean, German, Polish, Chinese Simplified, Chinese Traditional}.

Comment: What are the exact names of the ones you want?  The full line of text that shows, e.g. `Español — Spanish` vs. `Español (EE. UU.) — Spanish (US)` All the least, confirm for this one, or any one, and you should be able to adapt the _code_ for the other ones.

Comment: ah OK.

It would be:
Español — Spanish

Comment: Thierry Beliere, I do not know whether or not you've seen my answer yet, however, I've modified the code to removing the copy/paste aspect as it was not really necessary as I should have just set the _value_ to the **Search** _text box_ to the _value_ of `thisLanguage `, which of course it does now.

Answer (score 1):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

The *value* of the *property* `thisLanguage` needs to be set to that which will show in the *list* of the **Select a preferred language to add:** *sheet*, as it is set to the *value* of the *text box* on the **Select a preferred language to add:** *sheet*. This is necessary so **AppleScript** does not have to spend a lot of time searching the entire *list* as the target should now be it the top portion of the *list*.

Note that for, e.g., **Español** this script as is, is all that was necessary, however, on some languages one may get an additional *sheet* to reply to. For example, with **简体中文** (Simplified Chinese) one gets an additional **Select input sources to add:** *sheet*, and you will need to add additional *code* to handle it. You should be able to, from the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown below, figure out how to deal with it as there is already an example therein.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```aplescript
property thisLanguage : "Español"


--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Reveal the General tab of the Language
--  # & Region pane in System Preferences. 

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Language" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.Localization"
    activate
end tell

--  # System Events handles the rest.

tell application "System Events"
    launch
    delay 0.2
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        
        --  # Click the [+] button.
        
        click button 1 of group 2 of tab group 1 of window 1
        
        --  # Wait for sheet 1 to be available.
        
        set i to 0
        repeat until exists text field 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
            delay 0.1
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 30 then return
        end repeat
        
        --  # Search for: thisLanguage
        
        set the value of ¬
            text field 1 of ¬
            sheet 1 of ¬
            window 1 to ¬
            thisLanguage
        
        delay 1 --  # May need to be increased.
        
        --  # Get the row that matches thisLanguage.
        
        set theTargetRow to ¬
            the first row of ¬
                table 1 of ¬
                scroll area 1 of ¬
                sheet 1 of ¬
                window 1 whose value of ¬
            static text 1 of ¬
            UI element 1 is thisLanguage
        
        --  # Select the row that matches thisLanguage. 
        
        select theTargetRow
        
        --  # Click the Add button.
        
        click button 3 of sheet 1 of window 1
        
        --  # Wait for the sheet to change.
        
        set i to 0
        repeat until exists ¬
            button "Use English (US)" of ¬
            sheet 1 of window 1
            delay 0.1
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 30 then return
        end repeat
        
        --  # The button for thisLanguage 
        --  # should have focus, press enter.
        
        keystroke return
        
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.2

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

**Notes:**

The use of the `launch` *command* after `tell application "System Events"` is to try and help with a systemic issues in **UI Scripting** as a result of changes **Apple** had made in **macOS Big Sur**.

Also note that **UI Scripting** is often *kludgy* and prone to failure for a variety of reasons and why I have used the *error handling* that I have, however, one may need to add addition *error handling* and or `delay` *commands* and or adjust the *value* of existing ones, as needed.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Great work there user3439894. Thanks for your time on this.

There is still the last step of the pop up window "Your primary language has changed. Do you want to restart your computer now? .... with three buttons:
"Restart Now" which is the default one already selected
"Don't Restart"
"Cancel"

For my case I did not want to restart so I changed/added the following to your code from line:
keystroke return


....
keystroke return
end tell
delay 0.2
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
delay 0.2
keystroke tab
delay 0.2
keystroke tab
end tell